# Loading bitmap images in c# windows form application

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application with a few buttons, and when I click one button i want a bitmap image do be shown at the form screen. So, basically what I did was :

```
public static Bitmap[] images;

 Bitmap tileSheet = new Bitmap(filename);
            images = new Bitmap[256];


 public static void LoadImages(string filename)
        {
            Bitmap tileSheet = new Bitmap(filename);
            images = new Bitmap[256];

            for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
                {
                    images[y * 16 + x] = new Bitmap(32, 32);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(images[y * 16 + x]);
                    g.DrawImage(tileSheet, new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), new Rectangle(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
            }

        }
```

the function is telling me how the size of the image should be, and Ive declaired the bitmap, but how do I acctually load an image from my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Use openFileDialog to let user select the image.
Example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

Or you can just load the path of the image to your fileName.
Example: If your image is located at: C:\Image\Pic.jpg then add that to variable.